# Getting "RawUrl" with square bracket notation from System.Web.HttpRequest

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to get a member of an instance of the `System.Web.HttpRequest` class whenever a page is loaded in C#. Specifically the issue comes up whenever accessing the `RawUrl` member. Here's a simplified example, running on .Net 3.5.

```
string u0 = Request["RawUrl"]; // this gives me a value of null
string u1 = Request.RawUrl; // Using dot notation instead of square brackets works
string u2 = Request["Url"]; // However, "Url" works with square bracket notation
```

So my question is why is it that I can get the `Url` property of the Request with square bracket notation but can't do the same with `RawUrl`? The `Url` property is a `System.Uri` property whereas `RawUrl` is just a string so I'd imagine that it would be even easier to get. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike e.g. JavaScript where `foo["bar"]` and `foo.bar` are to ways to access the same member, in C# they mean completely different things - it's not just a different notation, it's a completely different method.

The square-brackets on an object call [the indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) if the object has one (and lead to a compiler error if the object doesn't). In the case of HttpRequest, the square brackets call into [HttpRequest.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Gets the specified object from the QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collections.

```
public string this[string key] { get; }
```

The `URL` is part of said items, the RawUrl is not. (That of course doesn't answer the question "Why is it not?" which I assume someone else has a good answer to, but my point is to address the possible misinformation that square brackets and dot notation are equivalent in C#)

Answer (score 1):

The HttpRequest indexer (how you access with the square brackets) accesses strings from the following locates in order.

1. `QueryString`
2. `FormCollection`
3. `Cookies`
4. `ServerVariables`

I have copy pasted the code (decompiled) for the indexer of `HttpRequest` at the bottom of this post.

Now to answer your question. The `RawUrl` is not part of any of those items but from a completly different location. The `RawUrl` is constructed by using two parts if valid.

1. The QueryString text
2. The Url string (unvalidated)

The code for the `RawUrl` construction spans over multiple classes and objects based on the request type. If you need more information on how the `RawUrl` is constructed I suggest you grab a decompiler and have a look.

Hope this helps

**HttpRequest indexer code from System.Web.dll (v4.5)**

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        string item = this.QueryString[key];
        if (item != null)
        {
            return item;
        }
        item = this.Form[key];
        if (item != null)
        {
            return item;
        }
        HttpCookie httpCookie = this.Cookies[key];
        if (httpCookie != null)
        {
            return httpCookie.Value;
        }
        item = this.ServerVariables[key];
        if (item != null)
        {
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because they are two completely different things. Having one doesn't automatically give you the other. E.g:

```
class YourClass {
    public string RawUrl { get; set; }
}
```

..gives you `YourClass.RawUrl`. Whereas:

```
class YourClass {
    public string this[string key] {
        get {
            return ...;
        }
    }
}
```

..gives you `YourClass["RawUrl"]`.

In terms of the `HttpRequest` object in ASP.NET.. it simply does not provide for "RawUrl" to be passed as a string. What it does internally, is uses the supplied string to check the following:

- Request.QueryString
- Request.Cookies
- Request.Form
- Request.ServerVariables

You can use `Request["HTTP_URL"]` (which is a server variable) to get *roughly* the equivalent of the `RawUrl` property.. you may have to combine it with other things though too.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion made me look through the `server_variables` and there wasn't a `HTTP_URL` but I found `HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL` which has exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!